# access a class and an array inside a class

Tags: c#

I want to put values inside my class array and a class inside a class. Below is my class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string typeOfPerson { get; set; }
    public Persondetails personDetails { get; set; }
    public Name[] names { get; set; }
}

public class Persondetails
    {
        public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }


public class Name
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string middleNames { get; set; }
    public string surName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to assign value to dateofBirth and names. I already initiated the person class:

```
        Person person = new Person();
        Persondetails pd = new Persondetails();
        pd.dateOfBirth = "12/03/2020";
```

How can I add date of birth to Person class. I also want to assign values to firstName, middleNames and surnames like so:

```
"names": [
                        {
                            "firstName": "ROGER",
                            "middleNames": "D",
                            "surName": "STANLEY"
                        }
                    ]
```

Any help will be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: I think you just want `person.personDetails = pd;` but it's not clear exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: That what I want. How do I put the values in the names array.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the size of an array, so unless you initialized the array before and know exactly which one you want to change, you should use a List. Then you can do the following:

```
public class Person
{
    public string typeOfPerson { get; set; }
    public Persondetails personDetails { get; set; }
    public List<Name> names { get; set; } = new List<Name>();
}

public void YourMethod()
{
    Person person = new Person();
    Persondetails pd = new Persondetails();
    pd.dateOfBirth = "12/03/2020";
    person.names.Add(new Name { firstName = "ROGER", middleName = "D", surName = "STANLEY" });
}
```

Comment: `names` list should be initialized before adding the values

Comment: I am creating a JSON file and I used the Visual studio utility that lets me paste the JSON as a class and that utility created arrays for me rather than List

Comment: That makes sense in some cases. It's just easier to use List, since it has very little overhead and is way more versatile than an array.